# Get continues records on scrolling

Tags: angularjs

Suppose  I have   n number of records. And those records should display on screen.
For first Time it should display 25 records and when user scrolls down then next 25 record should come like facebook does .Is there any solution?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, but the answer is yes this is possible.  You are looking for something called _lazy loading_.  There would be some work on your server side as well to support this.

Comment: https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
function loadMoreLeadsOnScroll() {

                if (_.isEqual($location.path(), ('/lead/list'))) {
                    var currentScroll = angular.element(this).scrollTop();
                    if (currentScroll > $scope.previousScroll) {
                        angular.element('#btnBackToTop').addClass('clsHighlightBackBtn');
                    }
                    $scope.previousScroll = currentScroll;
                    if (angular.element(document).height() - 50 <= angular.element(window).scrollTop() + angular.element(window).height()) {
                        //Your function here to load data from db
                    }
                }
                if ((angular.element(window).height() + 100) < angular.element(document).height()) {
                    angular.element('#top-link-block').removeClass('hidden').affix({
                        // how far to scroll down before link "slides" into view
                        offset: {top: 100}
                    });
                }
            }

            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            });

$scope.leadOnLoad = function () {
                angular.element(window).on('scroll', loadMoreLeadsOnScroll);
            };
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', $scope.leadOnLoad);
```

this is working for me

Comment: I have also used `ng-infinite` scroll, but it didn't work fine for me. that's why I wrote my own code.